# How can I stop showing camera image in my Scene? Unity

Tags: unity, ide

How can I stop showing camera image in my Scene in Unity? As you can see on the screenshot there is an image of a camera inside a player in the Scene view. How can I disable the image?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found on Unity forums

> Disable the gizmos. There should be a drop down bar for the scene view called Gizmos. Click on it and then uncheck the camera icon.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/790305/make-camera-invisible.html

Comment: I made a gif to visualize this: http://imgur.com/a/EhNNg